# Fold/unfold code section back using Cntrl + Z in Intelij IDEA

Tags: intellij-idea, folding

When I fold some code blocks (e.g. `for(){...}` loop or `if(){...}`) I often need to unfold it back. But my cursor can be far from the original position. I would like to do it using `Cntrl+Z` hotkey. But it doesn't catches fold/unfold actions.

Is it possible to track folding actions so they can be canceled by `Cntrl+Z`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no such feature in Intellij. Folding/Unfolding are not captured as "real" actions.

Unforunately nothing is mention in their [official documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/rider/Code_Folding.html), nor the `Settings/Preferences dialog (Ctrl+Alt+S), go to Editor | General | Code Folding` provide such feature.

Answer (score 1):

You might be able to get something similar with the code navigation keys:

Ctrl-Alt-Left = go back to previous cursor position

Ctrl-Alt-Right = go to next cursor position

Alternatively, you can use the Back and Forward buttons on your mouse to navigate through your location history.